# R Shiny - Removing UI using jQuery and onclick event handler

Tags: jquery, r, shiny, dom-events, shinyjs

The app below contains an actionButton `Add box` that creates a box when clicked. Each box has a AdminLTE `data-widget = "remove"` attribute, so each box has a remove button that is placed in the box-tools div in the box-header.

At the moment, clicking the remove button for a box only hides the box rather than removing it from the DOM. I have tried the jQuery function below:

```
$('[data-widget = \"remove\"]').click(function() {
                function removeBox (obj) {
                $(obj).closest('.newbox').remove();

                })
```

..which is called from the onclick handler that I have placed in the remove button tag (see server.R) but this doesn't seem to work.

Here is the reproducible code:

ui.R:

```
require(shinydashboard)
require(shinyjs)


# HEADER
header <- dashboardHeader()

# SIDEBAR
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(

  tags$head(
    tags$script("

                $('[data-widget = \"remove\"]').click(function() {
                function removeBox (obj) {
                $(obj).closest('.newbox').remove();

                })


                ")
    ))

# BODY
body <- dashboardBody(shinyjs::useShinyjs(),

                      box(title = "Months", status = "primary", width = 12, solidHeader = T, background = "navy",
                          tags$div(id = 'add'),
                          tags$div(class = "pull-right",
                                   actionButton("addbox", "Add box")
                                   )
                          )
                      )


ui = dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, shinyFeedback::useShinyFeedback())
```

server.R

```
server = function(input, output, session) {


  observeEvent(input$addbox, {
    id = paste0('box', input$addbox)
    insertUI(
      selector = '#add',
      ui = tags$div(class = "newbox",
                    id = id,
                    box(width = 12,
                        solidHeader = T,
                        title = div(h4(class = "box-title", paste("Month", input$addbox),
                                    div(class = "box-tools",
                                        tags$button(class = "btn btn-box-tool",
                                                    onclick = "removeBox(this)",
                                                    `data-widget` = "remove",
                                                    shiny::icon("remove")
                                                    )
                                        )
                                    ),

                                    selectizeInput(id, "Month name:", choices = month.name)

                                    )

                        ) #end tags$div
                    )
      )
    }) #end observeEvent


  } #end server
```

Where am I going wrong? I think I may have used an incorrect selector (`'[data-widget = \"remove\"]'`) but I have tried `.btn.btn-box-tool` to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add an onclick event handler with the `onclick` attribute of the button. So you don't need to add another one. Simply use this script:

```
  tags$head(
    tags$script("
function removeBox(obj) {
  $(obj).closest('.newbox').remove();
}")
    )
  )
```

And that's it. No need to set a `data-widget` attribute.

The script you wanted to use is weird:

```
$('[data-widget = \"remove\"]').click(function() {
  function removeBox (obj) { ......
```

The structure is

```
$('[data-widget = \"remove\"]').click(function() {
 ***action to perform when the user clicks***
})
```

In your script, you define a function as the "action to perform", this executes nothing.

Comment: That worked, thank you very much for your help. I am new to jQuery and had tried stuff like `$('[data-widget=\"remove\"]').click(function() {
                                        $(this).closest('.newbox').remove();
      });` as per a W3 tutorial, but couldn't figure out why it wasn't working.

Comment: @user51462 It seems that shinydashboard already attaches an onclick-event handler to the elements with the `data-widget="remove"` attribute. Maybe this event handler cancels the one you define. Otherwise your "stuff" should work.

Comment: Cheers. I hadn't realised that the values of the inputs in the box still remain in the input list even after removing the box. This is problematic because I want to loop through the boxes at a later stage and only want to include the inputs of boxes that are still open in the UI. Can I add something like `.children('input').val('null')` to the removeBox function to erase the input values of closed boxes from memory?

Comment: Or alternatively, would it be correct to decrement by 1 the ID of the inputs in the boxes that succeed the one being closed? `function removeLearner(obj) {
  var closed = $(obj).closest('.lrnrbox');
  
  closed.remove();
  closed.nextAll('lrnrbox').getElementById('input').{some function to subtract 1 from the id of the selectizeInputs in boxes succeeding the one being closed}
}`